# How can I click a specific li without an id or class?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a sample menu with sub-menus, when I click one of them, their respective drop down should appear. I want to know how to do it without putting an id or class because In the project I'm doing right now, I am asked to change the menu dropdown to be clickable instead of hover and I don't want to add an id or class in each of the li because it's a pretty long vertical menu.

HTML

```
<ul id="nav">
<li>Home
    <ul class="sub-nav">
        <li>Johnny</li>
        <li>Julie</li>
        <li>Jamie</li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li class="parent">About
    <ul class="sub-nav">
        <li>Johnny</li>
        <li>Julie</li>
        <li>Jamie</li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li>Contact</li>
```

CSS

```
#nav ul.sub-nav {
  display: none;
}

#nav ul.visible {
  display: block;
}
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('ul li').click(function() {
        $('ul li ul').toggleClass('visible');
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cRsZE/

Comment: Is this the real HTML you are using in your code or a sample ?

Comment: It's just a sample of my problem, I am currently working on a school web archive as an Intern.

Comment: Can you provide a real stucture or depth of your ul li elements in menu??

Comment: You target based on direct child etc. `$('ul > li')` and then use `$(this).find('ul')` inside the click handler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

not sure if this is what you want.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('li').click(function() {
        $(this).find('ul').toggleClass('visible');
    });
});
```

But it works for me

Comment: Everyone has a great answer but you were the first one to give me the answer I need, so I choose you.

Comment: I have to wait 4 mins to choose an answer.

Answer (score 0):

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('ul > li').click(function() {

            $(this).children('ul').toggleClass('visible');
        });
    });
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/cRsZE/770/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this, `.children()` will fetch the immediate children of current li element:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('li').click(function() {
        $(this).children('ul').toggleClass('visible');
    });
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/cRsZE/771/)